# Will a car file also work on Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty

At a customer they are thinking to replace their local WAS Server as development sever by the lightweight WLP.
They make use of car files to deploy configurations to new Websphere server or reinstall a was server.
Is it possible to use these car files also on WLP? Or is there another way to ship was configuration between servers.

Comment: Not sure if it answers your question so will just comment.  You might look at the [WebSphere Configuration Migration Toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Configuration_Migration_Tool) for tooling assistance in migrating to Liberty server config.  I'm not sure if it helps with .car files though, but may still be of interest.  See [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1404_vines2/1404_vines2.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing CAR archives won't be  usable, but there are (what I would describe as) superior ways with Liberty.

Liberty:

- uses more human editable configuration to begin with
- allows you to include xml snippets directly without an intermediate representation [twlp_setup_includes.html](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_setup_includes.html)
- allows the entire server + config + applications to be packaged up and relocated (see the "server package" command for details) [twlp_setup_package_server](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=phil&product=was-libcore-mp&topic=twlp_setup_package_server)